# Windows 7 Start Debugging SSIS package in VS2015 results in DTSDebugHost.exe blocked by group policy

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, dts, group-policy

I would like to debug an SSIS package in Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise where newest version of "SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2015" is installed.
If I start debugging, the following error occurs:

> "This programm was blocked by group policy...(Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)"

When I check eventviewer, I saw that "DTSDebugHost.exe" was blocking in following path:
`"%OSDRIVE%\USERS\<Username>\APPDATA\LOCAL\MICROSOFT\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\130\SSIS\110\X86\DTSDEBUGHOST.EXE"`

If I delete `DTSDebugHost.exe` in this APPDATA path, every time, I start debugging, the `DTSDebugHost.exe` will be copied from somewhere to this APPDATA folder and the execution will be blocked by group policy.

When I start debugging same SSIS-package in Visual Studio 2012 Premium, the debugging works fine, because `DTSDebugHost.exe` starts in the following directory:
`%PROGRAMFILES%\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\110\DTS\BINN\DTSDEBUGHOST.EXE`

How can I change the executing path of `DTSDebugHost.exe`? Or what would be the best fix for this issue?